# gtest detects method only when the method is implemented in .h, not in .cpp (cmake; issue happens after "make")

Tags: c++, googletest

I've been trying to get used to c++ with cmake and gtest (google test).

I'm trying to understand why this setup yields the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Project1::foo(int&)", referenced from:
    Project1Test_MethodBarDoesAbc_Test::TestBody()      in test_project1.cpp.o
        ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

when I run "make".

**When I implement methods in the .h file, things work fine; but when I only declare methods in the .h file and then implement it in the associated .cpp file, this error occurs.**

My test file: **test_project1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include "project1.h"

// tests outside of the class
TEST(IndependentMethod, ResetsToZero2) {
    int i = 0;
    independentMethod(i);
    EXPECT_EQ(0, i);
}
//...

// The fixture for testing the class
class Project1Test : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    // You can remove any or all of the following functions if its body
    // is empty.

    Project1Test() {
        // nothing here
    }
};

// Test case must be called the class above
TEST_F(Project1Test, MethodBarDoesAbc) {
    Project1 p;
    int i = 0;
    p.foo(i); // WHY CAN'T Project1::foo(int&) be detected here?!
    EXPECT_EQ(1, i);
}
```

Class definition: **project1.h**

```
#ifndef PROJECT1_H_
#define PROJECT1_H_

#include <iostream> // IO access

using namespace std;

class Project1 {

public:
    // why only detected if implemented here?
    // void foo(int &i) {
    //  i = 1;
    // }
    void foo(int &i);

};

void independentMethod(int &i) {
    // From experience, should be implemented in the .h, not the .cpp.
    // Otherwise, test can't find independentMethod, but WHY?
    i = 0;
}

#endif /* PROJECT1_H_ */
```

Implementation of Project1 class: **project1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "project1.h"

void Project1::foo(int &i) {
    i = 1;
}

int main() {
    // this works fine if I directly compile project1.cpp and run ./a.out
    cout << "do stuff" << endl;
    int x = 4;
    cout << x << endl;
    independentMethod(x);
    cout << x << endl;
    Project1 p;
    p.foo(x);
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

The procedure I go through to test is typical:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

I don't know if this is relevant, but here is my **CMakeLists.txt** file in the root of my project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Make PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR, PROJECT_BINARY_DIR, and PROJECT_NAME available
set(PROJECT_NAME MyProject)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall")

#set(COMMON_INCLUDES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include) if you want your own include/ directory
# then you can do include_directories(${COMMON_INCLUDES}) in other cmakelists.txt files

################################
# Normal files
################################
add_executable(project1 project1.cpp)

################################
# GTest
################################
# This adds another subdirectory, which has project(gtest)
add_subdirectory(lib/gtest-1.6.0)

enable_testing()

# Include the gtest library
# gtest_SOURCE_DIR is available due to project(gtest) above
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})

################################
# Unit Tests
################################
add_executable(runUnitTests test_project1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(runUnitTests gtest gtest_main)
add_test(NAME runUnitTests COMMAND runUnitTests)
```

I feel like the issue is due to some misunderstanding I have about implementing .cpp vs in .h. I know that templated functions must be implemented in .h, but I'm not templating anything. I just want to test.

Help appreciated.

Comment: You're not linking your program with the `project1` object code.  All your `runUnitTests` executable depends on is `test_project1.cpp`, and that's not enough.

Comment: Oh so the error is in my CMakeLists.txt file! Thanks - but how am I supposed to properly link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link to your runUnitTests executable with your own code in project1.cpp.

I'd favour making a library out out the guts of project1.cpp and move the main function into a separate file (e.g. main.cpp).  Then you can do

```
add_library(project1_lib project1.cpp project1.h)
add_executable(project1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(project1 project1_lib)

add_executable(runUnitTests test_project1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(runUnitTests project1_lib gtest gtest_main)
```

Comment: This is great - thanks! I have a small question: Is it unnecessary to have the extra .h file in add_library(project1_lib project1.cpp project1.h), so we can just do things of the form add_library(project1_lib project1.cpp) whenever we use add_library? (And I think the same is true for add_executable - we only need the .cpp.) This has just been inconsistent across the web - I was wondering which way is proper, because without the .h seems to work too.

Comment: @dmonopoly Yes - you don't *need* to list headers in `add_library` or `add_executable`, but adding them makes them appear in IDEs like Visual Studio.  It's for convenience only.